# Synchrony Bank Amazon store card - alerts for every transaction

Tags: credit-card

I want an alert for **every single transaction** on my card. Their website only has option for alerts for transactions over $50 minimum. I want to see every single transaction. How is this possible?

Comment: If they *only* have a check box for "send alert on transactions over $50", then ISTM that your options are limited: #1 Check the box. (Something is better than nothing!) #2 Complain to Synchrony. #3 Log into the website every day. (Mobile app should make that easy.)

Comment: This sounds like a question for your bank and/or the merchant in question, versus us internet strangers.

Comment: "I'd like 2 orange popsicles.  Sorry sir but we don't carry orange popsicles.  OK, I'll just take one then." If Amazon doesn't offer alerts for every single transaction then you're not going to get an alert for every single transaction, regardless of what you want.  Send a letter or e-mail them, requesting that they add this feature.

Comment: I asked because I thought I was missing something. Guess not. Guess they really are missing a feature every other card I have offers.

Comment: Hi Max, I have the same account. I know they have an option if the balance goes above a certain level and that is what I’ve set up. When I get home later today I will double check to see if there is anything that you were missing and will update my comment.

Comment: @BobBaerker - yours reminds me of a situation, long time ago. I was in a new state, and ordered a coffee. There, 'regular' meant 2 sugars + milk. Lesson learned. The next time I ordered, I tried to be very specific, black, no milk. Waitress said "sorry, we are out of milk. just cream." I replied "no problem. Black, no cream, please."

Comment: I have a card attached to google pay, I get a notice whenever that card is used now.  So that's an option I suppose, maybe Apple pay or Whatever Pay would work as well.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I didn't realise you were in the 1939 film [Ninotchka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninotchka) which contains [this YouTube clip of that joke](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TAO_NjrJ7M&feature=youtu.be), now often [attributed to Jean-Paul Satre](https://davedevine.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/the-sartre-joke/).

Comment: @TripeHound - hmm. So did Sartre steal it from the film or vice versa? And did I hear it somehow, and just recall it years later?

Comment: @Joe As far as I know, Sartre never said it, and whoever first came up with "_Satre asked for a coffee..._" never believed he said it: they just used the name because it's a "philosophical" joke (and, apparently, it ties in with his essay [Being and Nothingness](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Being_and_Nothingness), although I've not read it (but might now do)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

From the page to set alerts. As you noted, $50 min. Sorry.

I have other cards that offer a text when the card isn't present for a purchase. Every Amazon charge would ping me, no matter how small. But. I get 5% back using the store card.

Comment: If it helps any, the Amazon Prime branded Visa credit card from Chase offers the same rewards on Amazon purchases, and also provides the option to receive alerts for every transaction if you'd like. Synchrony has historically been quick to close accounts for non-use though, so if you try to have both special effort would need to be made to keep the store card account from getting auto-closed.

Comment: Good point. In my case, I don’t recall what made my decision to choose the store-only version. I need to revisit that decision as well.

Comment: I originally went for the store card I as already had a regular card I was fine with, and actually don't even recall if they had that option at the time or if it had the same rewards, and Amazon seemed like one of the only places I could think of that I spent enough money that it made sense to have a "store card" based on their special offers at the time. They've changed so much over the last few years I'm not even sure the store card is the same as I remember - moving boldly forward to being a Prime Citizen, and all that :)